# Gerrit Code Review - Retrieve the file names from the change

Tags: python, gerrit

**I am working on Gerrit Code review tool. I want to fetch the data about the change with Gerrit rest api.
I am able to get the other content but not able to fetch the files changed in the review.**
**code for getting the details of the change is:**

```
gerrit_username = os.environ.get('GERRIT_USERNAME')
gerrit_password = os.environ.get('GERRIT_PASSWORD')
gerrit_url = os.environ.get('GERRIT_URL')

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self.gerrit_username, self.gerrit_password)
rest = GerritRestAPI(url=self.gerrit_url, auth=auth)

review_details = rest.get('changes/' + self.review_id + '/detail/q?o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

This code gives me a dictionary containing info like id, project, owner name etc but not file name.

Is there any different mechanism to get the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `CURRENT_FILES` parameter in the query as per [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#current-files).

See in the following example the file names in the `file` section of the JSON response:

```
> curl "https://review.gerrithub.io/changes/?q=I79609cdaf636dc712b3a1e9cffb25aef98f69123&o=CURRENT_FILES&o=CURRENT_REVISION"
)]}'
[
  {
    "id": "NexellCorp%2Fandroid_platform_packages_apps_Car_Launcher~pie-dev~I79609cdaf636dc712b3a1e9cffb25aef98f69123",
    "project": "NexellCorp/android_platform_packages_apps_Car_Launcher",
    "branch": "pie-dev",
    "hashtags": [],
    "change_id": "I79609cdaf636dc712b3a1e9cffb25aef98f69123",
    "subject": "Car Launcher: fix for Car Launcher UI",
    "status": "NEW",
    "created": "2020-04-08 10:52:36.000000000",
    "updated": "2020-04-08 10:53:49.000000000",
    "submit_type": "REBASE_ALWAYS",
    "mergeable": true,
    "insertions": 0,
    "deletions": 1,
    "total_comment_count": 0,
    "unresolved_comment_count": 0,
    "has_review_started": true,
    "_number": 489084,
    "owner": {
      "_account_id": 1017471
    },
    "current_revision": "a0cfbc22500e0d15257fc13e483bacc5104ec000",
    "revisions": {
      "a0cfbc22500e0d15257fc13e483bacc5104ec000": {
        "kind": "REWORK",
        "_number": 1,
        "created": "2020-04-08 10:52:36.000000000",
        "uploader": {
          "_account_id": 1017471
        },
        "ref": "refs/changes/84/489084/1",
        "fetch": {
          "anonymous http": {
            "url": "https://review.gerrithub.io/NexellCorp/android_platform_packages_apps_Car_Launcher",
            "ref": "refs/changes/84/489084/1"
          }
        },
        "files": {
          "AndroidManifestQ.xml": {
            "lines_deleted": 1,
            "size_delta": -39,
            "size": 2659
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "requirements": []
  }
]
```